# `nvidia-smi` is not installed with the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa for nvidia-* drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, ppa

I'm trying to install the nvidia drivers via:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
```

They seem to install (though I don't actually know for sure if I'm running on my Nvidia graphics card or my Intel card).

I expect to be able to run `nvidia-smi` to take a look at the Nvidia GPU (nvidia-smi is a very funamental monitoring tool included with the nvidia drivers).

```
$ nvidia-smi
nvidia-smi: command not found
```

But I just get a command not found after this installation.

How do I install `nvidia-smi` using this ppa? Am I not understanding something? Are these PPAs incomplete? I'm trying to configure this for tensorflow, so CUDA & CuDNN libraries are up next. But I can't deal with that until I can at least validate that the GPU drivers are properly installed, and the only way I know to do that is via `nvidia-smi`. On the nvidia forums I'm told that this tool normally installs with the driver and they suggest not using the PPA (but their supported installation process is even more painful).

Comment: Why not use Launchpad email & ask the ppa's admin why they don't provide nvidia-smi? (they do now for 18.04 but in 18.04 the repo package is probably better at this point..

Comment: What is this launchpad email you refer to?

Comment: When you go to the ppa page right above the `Overview of published packages` you'll see a `For questions and bugs with software in this PPA please contact` link. click on it > on the resulting page look to far right, you'll see a `contact this teams admins` link. That'll open up an email dialog. Note that you likely needed to be logged into launchpad to use. If that is onerous to you, (setting up a LP account), post back, i'll ask for you..

Comment: Otherwise it may be possible to use `ubuntu-bug` to file a bug. Most ppa packages can't use ubuntu-bug but maybe that ppa has a hook. If so tag the bug  `Proprietary GPU Drivers ppa` or something. ( the ppa page doesn't mention so maybe not ..

Comment: It should be in `/usr/lib/nvidia-390/bin/nvidia-smi`. Use `ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-390/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi` to create a link.

Comment: Hi David, please execute `sudo lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`. If the output includes the message `Kernel driver in use: nvidia` - then the NVIDIA drivers are properly installed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had almost the same issue with *nvcc*. Fixed this way:

```
sudo apt install libcuda1-390 nvidia-opencl-icd-390
```

Since these packages have been kept back

Comment: These references were useful, thanks. Though for posterities sake, `nvidia-smi` actually is installed with `nvidia-390` my actual problem stemmed from them not getting loaded correctly and paths not being set up properly.  `nvidia-smi` resides, by default, in `/usr/lib/nvidia-390/bin/nvidia-smi`

Comment: @DavidParks, so how did you solve this problem?. Did you add the directory to path? I have the same kind of problem. Please help.

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled the whole bloody OS. I tried everything, posted everywhere for a month, I must have dumped 40+ hours into the problem. I've written off dual graphics cards and nvidia installations as a lost cause on linux. Keep it as simple as possible, don't get fancy, and you might just get something that resembles a working environment. Dual graphics cards and better virtual memory management are my two biggest wish-they-worked-like-windows wishlist items.